# Nintendo's recent emulation patent: why?

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, application, us20140349751

This particular application is all over the news today: [HAND-HELD VIDEO GAME PLATFORM EMULATION](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=2&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=Nintendo.AS.&OS=AN/Nintendo&RS=AN/Nintendo)

I'm approaching this out of sheer curiosity. It is my understanding that emulating other hardware is a concept that predates the internet, *and* Nintendo, and more to the point of this patent, emulation of Nintendo's video game consoles has been done for [quite literally every console the company has ever released](http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/best-emulators/), by various individuals and groups.

This patent makes one claim:

> 7. A method of adapting an emulator, the method comprising: executing, on a processor, an emulator capable of running a plurality different binary applications; recognizing, by the processor, an identity of a binary application based on an inspection of the binary application; automatically adapting, by the processor, a behavior of the emulator to the binary application based on the recognized identity of the binary application; and generating, by the processor, an audio visual presentation using the adapted behavior of the emulator.

This sounds like the exact behavior of any of the programs from the second link above.

A description of any modern emulator:

It loads specially-formatted binary files, in the form of ROM images. These images contain information as to the format of the rest of the data in their headers, as well as a name that's used to trigger special behavior from the emulator, these can take the form of compatibility or speed workarounds to deal with certain code in the program being emulated. The result of this executed code is then output to a monitor and speakers.

Comment: There's an extensive discussion about this application at https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8672919

Comment: Just to reiterate, this is just a publication of patent application. It has yet to be examined, yet alone granted.

Answer (score 2):

From that claim, it looks like they have a universal emulator that decides which console it emulates by looking at the game's binaries.

Comment: Yes, the phrases like "plurality different binary applications" "adapting...a behavior of the emulator to the binary application"